# DependsOn best practices in AWS Cloud Formation (example included)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, infrastructure-as-code

What are the best practices for using Depends On in CloudFormation? I believe from what I read, it's not recommended to do so in Azure and to minimise it's use.

I want to put a DependsOn relationship between, for example, an ASG Policy, and an ASG Group.

[image]

In the above picture, you can see that ASG Policy has a field **AutoScalingGroupName**.

Therefore, ASG Policy depends on AutoScaling Group creation.

Would a depends On relationship exist between these two?

Comment: What is your actual template?

Comment: @Marcin Sorry not sure what you mean?

Comment: The actual cloudformation template that you want to deploy to AWS?

Comment: Haven't started writing the template, just created this to map the relationships out first

Comment: @Marcin In my template I want to include an autoscaling group and add policies to this autoscaling group. It follows that an autoscaling policy can't be functional without an autoscaling group, so my thinking was...I'd expect there to be a DependsOn relationship between these two :S ?

Comment: Ok, but what is your template? Did you write any template?

Comment: @Marcin no, I haven't written anything yet. I was told to create the above first

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, any resource in a CloudFormation template that refers to another resource will automatically have an *implied* `DependsOn`.

For example:

```yaml
  PrivateRouteTable1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName} Private Routes (AZ1)

  DefaultPrivateRoute1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable1
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway1
```

`DefaultPrivateRoute1` will have an implied `DependsOn` with `PrivateRouteTable1`  and `NatGateway1`.

So, the only time you particularly need to add a `DependsOn` is when there is no direct relationship, but there is an order of creation required. Here's an example of that:

```yaml
  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  NatGateway1EIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    DependsOn: InternetGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
```

In this case, a `DependsOn` was defined between the Elastic IP Address and the InternetGateway. This is helpful because there is no direct relationship between an Elastic IP address and an Internet Gateway (which is linked to a VPC).

I have seen situations where an Amazon EC2 instance had failures in its User Data script because other resources were not 'ready', so the script was unable to access the Internet. It can be difficult to diagnose such situations because they can be transient. Therefore, you might want to specifically add some `DependsOn` references where there is no directly reference between required resources.

Comment: Thanks so much for the effort! This clears it up - implicit dependsOn. I also found some other info about when DependsOn will likely be required here for anyone else that might find this helpful 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html#gatewayattachment